# Texto com 2 alinhamentos diferentes

Tags: html, tabela-html, css

```css
.table, th, td {
    border: solid #000000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 3px;
}
.th, td {
    border-width: 3px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" "float:left" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th align="center" bgcolor="#def2d9" colspan="3">1 STARTER</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Users</th> 
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>M00</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td>Base Package</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SP40</td>
    <td align="center">NA</td>
    <td>Training</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="justify" colspan="3"><p><b>PRICE:</b> 9 900,00€
    <p>+
    <p>131,67€
    <p>Monthly Subscription</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Boa tarde,

Estou aqui à umas belas horas a pesquisar como poderei resolver este problema.
Eu tenho uma tabela e na última linha eu coloco o preço do produto, em que o "PRICE:" precisa ficar alinhado à esquerda e o valor precisar ficar alinhado à direita, isto na mesma linha.
Vou deixar aqui o código HTML e o CSS.

Comment: Olá Melissa, será que você poderia colocar o `width=100%` na tabela apenas para vermos melhor o que deseja?
Você quer que o PRICE fique à esquerda e o valor à direita, somente isso?

Comment: @Randrade vou então alterar com o width=100%, e sim quero apenas isso, mas tem de ficar na mesma linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias de formas de se fazer o que deseja. A forma mais simples que vejo é adicionar um `span` com o alinhamento à direita para o valor, desta forma:

```css
.table,
th,
td {
  border: solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 3px;
}

.th,
td {
  border-width: 3px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table style="width:100%" "float:left" class="table">
    <tr>
      <th align="center" bgcolor="#def2d9" colspan="3">1 STARTER</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Users</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M00</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td>Base Package</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SP40</td>
      <td align="center">NA</td>
      <td>Training</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="justify" colspan="3">
        <p class="left">
          <b>PRICE</b>
          <span class="right">9 900,00€</span>
        </p>
        <p>+</p>
        <p>131,67€</p>
        <p>Monthly Subscription </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Resultou, muito obrigada